# When submitting this button inside a datatable doesnt submit the right row id

Tags: php, html, datatable, form-submit

I have a dynamic table which is set inside a foreach, so for each item of the array fetched create a new row. I have in the last column a button for each row. When clicking that submit button I am suppose to receive the id of that in PHP. Submission is being done correctly, but I am receiving the wrong id in PHP. Its basically taking the last id of the array when submitting. Any idea why?

**Here is the table:**

```
<form method="post" id="frm-example" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . '?' . e(http_build_query($_GET)); ?>">
            <table id="example" class="display compact">
            <thead>
                <th>Device</th>                    
                <th>Sales date</th>
                <th>Client comments</th>  
                <th>Breakage count</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($arr_cases_devices as $cases) {  ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $cases['name']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $cases["sales_date"]; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $cases["dev_comment"]; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>          
                           <input type="hidden" name="device_id_breakage" value="<?php echo $cases["Dev_Id"]; ?>" />
                           <button type="submit" name="see_rma">See RMA</button>                       
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
   </form>
```

When clicking on `see_rma` this is what I receive in PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['see_rma'])) {
   $selected_dev = e($_POST['device_id_breakage']);
   print_r($selected_dev); // prints the "Dev_Id" of the last row, not of the row clicked
}
```

If I try printing `$cases["Dev_Id"];` inside loop in the table, it prints perfectly fine, so it prints the Dev_Id of each row correctly. So, that means there is nothing wrong with the array or data. I don't why is this happening but it's for sure the first time I am having this issue.

I do this in many other tables but for some reasons in this one its not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `<input>` elements with the same name within your form, and all of them are going to be submitted when you submit the form, but PHP can only get one of them. That's why you end up with only the last one in `$_POST`.

It looks like you should be able to fix this by just moving some attributes from the hidden input into the button (replacing the hidden input).

```
<button type="submit" name="device_id_breakage" value="<?php echo $cases["Dev_Id"]; ?>">
    See RMA
</button>
```

Only the button that was clicked will be submitted. Note that after changing the name of the button, you won't have `see_rma` in `$_POST` any more, so if you have any code that depends on that you'll need to change it to look for the other name instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thats not very correct. I have used hidden input fields to submit data to PHP almost all the time and it works perfectly fine but in this particular case its not working for some unknown reasons. You said that I have multiple inputs with the same name but I checked and there is ONLY ONE `<input type="hidden" name="device_id_breakage" value="<?php echo $cases["Dev_Id"]; ?>" />` . One more thing, its not true that ONLY the button will be submitted, the entire form will be submitted together with all the values that it contains.

Comment: However, I placed the value inside the button so it's working now. But still, I am very curious to know why wasn't it working with the hidden input field.

Comment: Yes, hidden inputs generally do work. I didn't mean to imply that they wouldn't work in any case, just that there was a problem in this case. The code in your question outputs that input in a foreach loop, without altering the name attribute, so I would have to assume that you'd see multiple inputs with the same name if you viewed the page source. If not, maybe some other code is modifying them later.